# defaultValue or value not working on FormItem ANTD

Tags: reactjs, typescript, antd

I tried using the following code and the field never gets bind. The onChange property works well

```
const { getFieldDecorator, getFieldError, isFieldTouched } = this.props.form;
const NameError = isFieldTouched("Name") && getFieldError("Name");

<FormItem validateStatus={NameError ? "error" : ""} help={NameError || ""}>
  {getFieldDecorator("Name", {
    //initialValue: this.state.Data.Name,
    rules: [{ required: true, message: "Please input the component name!" }]
  })(
    <Input
      className="form-control"
      type="text"
      name="Name"
      defaultValue={this.state.Data.Name}
      onChange={this.onChange}
    />
  )}
</FormItem>
```

Am I missing something? I even used `input` instead of `Input`

**EDIT**
On `componentDidMount` method I get the data from an API:

```
fetch('http://localhost:5728/Fields/get/' + this.state.Data.Id)
          .then(results=>{
            return results.json()
          })
          .then(data=>{

            this.setState({
                Data: {
                    Id: data.field.Id,
                    Name: data.field.Name,
                    Description: data.field.Description,
                    Value: data.field.Value
                }
              })

          })
```

I tried using `initialValue`, but it only works when the state value is set on the `constructor` method. When calling the API, the change is not reflected.

Comment: `initialValue` member in second argument of `getFieldDecorator` should work. You don't need to pass `defaultValue` into `Input`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response. You know, I tried that, but I had a problem, please see the edit.

Comment: Ah, ok. That make sense then. Idk how to fix it properly, but as a workaround I'd 1) extract the form into a separate component, 2) mount extracted component only after loading complete (and pass the data as a props). There might be a better solution, though.

Comment: Oh, very cool approach. I really like it, but one question, is this a good practice? Sorry for the silly question I am very new with ReactJS.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The [docs states](https://ant.design/components/form/) that:

> You cannot set value of form **control** via value **defaultValue** prop, and you should set default value with **initialValue in getFieldDecorator** instead.
>
> You shouldn't call setState manually, please **use this.props.form.setFieldsValue** to change value programmatically.

So you just need to call `setFieldsValue` when the data is loaded from the backend:

```
fetch('http://localhost:5728/Fields/get/' + this.state.Data.Id)
      .then(results=>{
        return results.json()
      })
      .then(data=>{

        this.props.form.setFieldsValue({
                Id: data.field.Id,
                Name: data.field.Name,
                Description: data.field.Description,
                Value: data.field.Value
          })
      })
```

Or shorter, if `data.field` from backend totally matches the field names:

```
this.props.form.setFieldsValue(data.field)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works. One question tho, about this "You shouldn't call setState manually". The way I see it , I still need to use both, right? setState (after webapi call and onChange) and this.props.form.setFieldsValue(data.field). Otherwise, how is react going to know what the current state is? Should I tie somehow "setFieldsValue" with my state name(s)?

Comment: Good question. You can pull data using `props.form.getFieldValue`/`props.form.getFieldsValue`. However, if your component state uses additional data (that is not in form), I think you can use both, from my view it shouldn't affect the antd form logic.

Comment: I received error:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'setFieldsValue' of undefined

Comment: @HassanAliShahzad if you use antd version > 4.x then, you have to use hooks: `const [form] = Form.useForm()`, and then you can use `form.setFieldsValue(...)`

Comment: Thanks a lot! I had the same issue with defaultValue.
antd Datepicker's defaultValue is not properly working in Form.Item, So I use `setFieldsValue(obj)` instead of defaultValue to set default DatePicker
then work magically! great answer!

Answer (score 6):

you can use hook, too

```
import { Form } from "antd"

const [form] = Form.useForm();

 fetch('api')
      .then(results=>{
        return results.json()
      })
      .then(data=>{
        form.setFieldsValue({
           sample: data.dataYouWant
        });


<Form form = {form}>
   <Form.Item name = "sample">
       <Input />
   </Form.Item>
</Form>
```

Comment: Adding few more details about the code would help others understand your answer better.

Answer (score 4):

For Class component V4:

```
class Demo extends React.Component {
  formRef = React.createRef();

  componentDidMount() {
    this.formRef.current.setFieldsValue({
      username: 'Bamboo',
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Form ref={this.formRef}>
        <Form.Item name="username" rules={[{ required: true }]}>
          <Input />
        </Form.Item>
      </Form>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I think the most guaranteed way is to use ref. Do you agree with me?